SQL SELECT best set for multiple exercises
Sorry for the bad title.
If have an SQLite database with a table with workout Sets like this:
id: INT,
exerciseId: Int,
weight: Double,
repCount: Int,
completedAt: Date

Now I want to get the best Set of every exercise. I can do it for a single exercise (with id=123) like so:
SELECT *
FROM Set
WHERE exerciseId = 123   
ORDER BY weight DESC, repCount DESC, completedAt ASC  
LIMIT 1

My question is, how would a query look like, that would give me the best set for all exercises? Is that even possible? I tried with GROUP BY etc. but since 'best' is derived from multiple columns that does not work correctly.

How do you define best? do you want the output to have Nr1 from every excercise no matter the ID? or do you want to some sort of determine 1 ID which is your best Set based on decisionmaking of counting all excercises together?

@LMA best is the one with highest weight first, secondarily with highest repcount and thirdly with oldest date. So if there is only ine set with 100kg that is the best. If there are more, the best is the one with most reps. If that is also equal the best is the one with oldest date. You can see that from my query as well.

@Ridcully what SQLite version are you using ?

@ErgestBasha I'm doing this for Android and I think the Sqlite version differs depending on version of Android. My app has minSDK=26 which means, Sqlite is version 3.18 or higher (according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary)

Window function would be the best as shared in the above answers, I wanted to share another approach, I have compared the results with window functions and it shows the same result set
Fiddle
SELECT s.*
FROM Set1 s
WHERE s.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM Set1
    WHERE exercise_id = s.exercise_id
    ORDER BY weight DESC, rep_count DESC, completed_at ASC
    LIMIT 1
);


This sounds like using RANK() (or ROW_NUMBER()) would work here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY exerciseId
                           ORDER BY weight DESC, repCount DESC, completedAt) rnk
    FROM Set
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;


From 3.25.0 version, are windows function supported, worth mentioning in the answer

The solution looks good but when trying it in AndroidStudio's AppInspection I get this error at the '(' before PARTITION BY: , FROM, GROUP, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE or comma expected, got '('.
The Sqlite Version is 3.44 so the window functions should be there, but somehow it's not working :-(

Based on what I understand a Window Function is what you want
WITH RankedSets AS (
    SELECT
        exerciseId,
        weight,
        repCount,
        completedAt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY exerciseId
            ORDER BY weight DESC, repCount DESC, completedAt ASC
        ) AS rank
    FROM workout_Sets
)
SELECT
    exerciseId,
    weight,
    repCount,
    completedAt
FROM RankedSets
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY exerciseId;

What this does:
ROW_NUMBER with Over and Partition By and Order by combined assigns ranks to each row within the excerciseId group. based on weight it descends, then by repCount and the date. This handles the ties as expected so even if the same weight is multiple times existing it will directly look which has more reps and even if its still a tie it picks the oldest date. I personally choose window functions over subqueries because i find them a lot cleaner for this approach

Was ChatGPT used for this answer? \:-|

No it was not I had this answer prepped because we had a discussion in my company 2 days ago to kind of drag devs from subqueries away. I just renamed the fields to fit better for OP

The solution looks good but when trying it in AndroidStudio's AppInspection I get this error at the '(' before PARTITION BY: , FROM, GROUP, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE or comma expected, got '('.
The Sqlite Version is 3.44 so the window functions should be there, but somehow it's not working :-(

If your Android client is correctly configured i cant really pinpoint the error. maybe its your client or something else. for me it works... hmm... maybe you have to opt for subqueries god knows why
